# Is str.split(someString).join(someOtherString) equivalent to a replace?

Tags: javascript, regex, string, algorithm

So I know that, for example, `"This is a test".split("i").join("j")` has the effect of replacing every instance of `"i"` with `"j"`. I'm curious about whether that procedure of splitting and joining is exactly **equivalent** to using a Regex replace or whether there are any corner cases where for given strings `str1`, `str2` and `str3` we have

```
str1.split(str2).join(str3) != str1.replace(/str2/g,str3)
```

EDIT: For clarification, by `str1.replace(/str2/g,str3)` I mean a hypothetical `str1.replaceAll(str2,str3)` that replaces all occurrences of `str2` with `str3`

Comment: I don't know, is it? Seems like it would be pretty easy to test your hypothesis rather than post a question here.

Comment: @BrianDriscoll testing corner cases isn't trivial.

Comment: @ReutSharabani I didn't say it was trivial, but I don't think it's that difficult, either. It's pretty easy to see where split().join() will yield different/unexpected results when compared to a regex replace.

Comment: You can't use capture groups with `.split().join()`.

Comment: @FelixKling I assume OP is talking about replacing very simple strings, i.e. not using any regex functionality. Otherwise the answer would be fairly obviously, "No". But technically, yes you can use capture groups in `split` but it would work out rather differently (try `"foo".split(/(o)/).join('o')`).

Comment: @p.s.w.g: Yeah, I rather meant in the replacement part. *"I assume OP is talking about replacing very simple strings, i.e. not using any regex functionality."* Possibly :) I assumed that `str2` could also be a regular expression. Maybe it can't (given that the title also says "someString").

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, they are not equivalent. Here's one edge case…

Splitting by an empty string returns an array of each character in the original string:

```
"foo".split('') --> ["f", "o", "o"]
```

And you might think that an empty regular expression (`RegExp('', 'g')` or `/(?:)/`) would work the same, especially if you test it out using split:

```
"foo".split(/(?:)/g) --> ["f", "o", "o"]
```

However, in the replace method, it works a bit differently. Because it matches every zero-width position in the string, including the zero-width position *before the first character* and *after the last character*:

```
"foo".replace(/(?:)/g, '-') --> "-f-o-o-"
```

This happens because the split method in a sense 'starts' at first character and 'stops' at the last character, whereas the replace method is allowed to 'start' *before* the first character and 'stop' *after* the last. So any regular expression that matches the beginning or end of the string will behave differently.

```js
var testCases = [/(?:)/g, /^/g, /$/g, /\b/g, /\w*/g];
$.each(testCases, function(i, r) {
    $("#t").append(
      $("<tr>").append(
        $("<td>").text(r.toString()),
        $("<td>").text("foo bar".split(r).join('-')),
        $("<td>").text("foo bar".replace(r, '-'))
      )
    );
  });
```

```css
* { font-family:monospace; }
table { border-collapse: collapse }
td,th { border:1px solid #999; padding: 3px; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table id="t">
  <tr>
    <th>RegExp</th>
    <th>str.split(r).join('-')</th>
    <th>str.replace(r, '-')</th>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to go very far to see where `split().join()` will vary from `replace()`. Consider the case where you want to replace all occurrences of the personal pronoun "me" in a string with "myself". `split().join()` will replace all occurrences of the alphabetic sequence "me" without regard to usage, so the string "I need some time for me" will become "I need so**myself** ti**myself** for **myself**".

However, with an appropriate regex you can capture and replace only the word "me", so your result will be "I need some time for myself".

Comment: That is with the constrained that the value passed to `.split` is a string, not a regular expression. Because the following works fine: `"I need some time for me".split(/\bme\b/).join('myself')`.

Answer (score 0):

TL;DR: No.

Your code is an equivalent of hypothetical `string.replaceAll(str,repl)` but not of `string.replace(str,repl)`

Problem is that `string.replace("str","bystr")` replaces only first occurrence of "str". But your code replaces all occurrences.

Comment: I think OP is aware of that--notice how question has a `g` flag. I think what OP means is, "Is the hypothetical `string.replaceAll(str, repl)` fully equivalent to the hypothetical `string.replace(RegExp(RegExp.escape(str), "g"), repl)`?"

Comment: @p.s.w.g Depends on how that hypothetical replaceAll method is defined in another hypothetical ECMA specification. As for me it shall be very close to that.

Comment: @p.s.w.g Yes, my question is based on a hypothetical `replaceAll`