# Regular Expression replacement in Python

Tags: python, python-re

I have a regular expression to match all instances of 1 followed by a letter. I would like to remove all these instances.

```
EXPRESSION = re.compile(r"1([A-Z])")
```

I can use re.split.

```
result = EXPRESSION.split(input)
```

This would return a list. So we could do

```
result = ''.join(EXPRESSION.split(input))
```

to convert it back to a string.

or

```
result = EXPRESSION.sub('', input)
```

Are there any differences to the end result?

Comment: Did you mean `result = ''.join(...)`?

Comment: Do you have any cases where you suspect there might be a difference?

Comment: Yes sorry `''.join(..)` would make more sense! I don't but I am not too familiar with re and would like to make sure I'm not overlooking something.

Comment: There might be a difference in performance, but not in the result.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the results are different. Here is a simple example:

```
import re

EXPRESSION = re.compile(r"1([A-Z])")

s = 'hello1Aworld'

result_split = ''.join(EXPRESSION.split(s))
result_sub = EXPRESSION.sub('', s)

print('split:', result_split)
print('sub:  ', result_sub)
```

Output:

```
split: helloAworld
sub:   helloworld
```

The reason is that because of the capture group, `EXPRESSION.split(s)` includes the `A`, as noted in the documentation:

> `re.split = split(pattern, string, maxsplit=0, flags=0)`
>
> Split the source string by the occurrences of the pattern,
>   returning a list containing the resulting substrings. **If
>   capturing parentheses are used in pattern, then the text of all
>   groups in the pattern are also returned as part of the resulting
>   list.** If maxsplit is nonzero, at most maxsplit splits occur,
>   and the remainder of the string is returned as the final element
>   of the list.

---

When removing the capturing parentheses, i.e., using

```
EXPRESSION = re.compile(r"1[A-Z]")
```

then so far I have not found a case where `result_split` and `result_sub` are different, even after reading [this answer to a similar question about regular expressions in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37282015/is-str-splitsomestring-joinsomeotherstring-equivalent-to-a-replace/37282562#37282562), and changing the replacement string from `''` to `'-'`.

Comment: Very interesting thanks. So removing those parentheses is very important? Shows you how much I know about re.